# How can I associate data - a string, integer or enum member - with a Gtk::ComboBoxText item?

Tags: c++, combobox, gtk, associative-array, gtkmm

I am using `gktmm 3.0` on an Ubuntu 12.04 box with the default GCC toolchain.

In the C# world, the `ComboBox` class has a `ComboxBox.item[n].value` property, which allows you to associate each item in the comboBox with data.

I am looking for something similar in the `Gtk::ComboBoxText`class. How can I associate data - a string, integer or enum member for example - with a particular `Gtk::ComboBoxText`item?

I know that many frameworks provide a generic`data` pointer on widgets for such use, as this is quite a common need.

Is there something in `Gtk::ComboBoxText` class or one of its parent classes that might allow me accomplish this, or do I need to set up such an association myself, using a map or other associative collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gtk::ComboBoxText append, insert() and prepend() methods allows you to specify an ID string as well as the human-visible text. For instance:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1ComboBoxText.html#a19e80f4e451e23d2c00d3fb11023f9f2

But it would be clearer and more type-safe to use Gtk::ComboBox and define an actual underlying model that contains the associated data. This example uses an int, but you could use other types or use more columns:
https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/combobox-example-full.html.en

Comment: I'm using Glade so my options are somewhat limited.But`id` does seem help accomplish my goal.

Comment: You don't need to use the GtkTreeModel that Glade defines for you, and it's generally a bad idea to do so in gtkmm. By defining the model in your code you get type safety in your code.

Comment: Could be - I'm still finding my way with Glade. Just got very tired of doing all the widget manipulation by hand in my code - have other things to do - GUI is not my specialty. I understand there is a balance to strike between what you do in Glade and what you do in your code.